# Application force stops in For loop when checking the list for Wifi

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

Below is the code used to connect particular wifi device, ends up in force stop when  for loop starts.

```
String networkSSID = "iriss";
String networkPass = "123456789";
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   
conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

for (WifiConfiguration wifilist : list) {
    if(wifilist.SSID != null && wifilist.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(wifilist.networkId, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
        Toast.makeText(this, "...Active...", 70000).show();
        break;
    }           
}
```

When executing the above code, the application force stops at for (WifiConfiguration wifilist : list) and fires the below error

```
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775): Process: com.example.shuttlecock, PID: 2775
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at com.example.shuttlecock.Webview.ConnectToParticularWifi(Webview.java:110)
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at com.example.shuttlecock.Webview.access$0(Webview.java:48)
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at com.example.shuttlecock.Webview$3.onClick(Webview.java:173)
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
10-22 07:36:54.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2775):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you make sure `list` is not null? [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks()) sais:"Upon failure to fetch or when when Wi-Fi is turned off, it can be null. "

Comment: @Stefan Beike,  its the for loop.. "for (WifiConfiguration wifilist : list) "

Comment: @Fildor.. altered some code.. I believe its working fine now.. Will get back to you, if I got any issues..

Comment: @Stefan Beike and Fildor.. Thanks much for your help..